# MYSQL Error 1062 duplicate enetry for key PRIMARY

Tags: mysql

I am new to all this, and I am struggling with why it keeps saying this.

Here is my code:

```
Use Client_info;

Create table Session_Log (
    Client_ID INT,
    session_ID INT,
    Staff_ID INT,
    Session_Duration varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("2245","22897","6574","2hours");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    value ("9975","01287","1089","1hour");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("3847","25601","5160","3hours");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("7420","25601","1089","1hour");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("3449","38145","8793","2hours");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("1125","22897","1125","4hours");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("1884","20076","5160","1hour");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("4937","01287","2265","3hours");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("2985","22897","6574","3hours");

INSERT INTO Session_log (Client_ID, Session_ID, Staff_ID,Session_Duration)
    Value ("1129","25601","8793","1hour");
```

I literally don't know much about coding so please be kind and patient with me.

#### Full `CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE session_log (
  Client_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  session_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  Staff_ID int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  Session_Duration varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (Staff_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Sorry, but the above code alone will certainly _not_ result in that error. Simply because there is no primary key / index defined at all.

Comment: Your code is fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68af2.  Perhaps you have a trigger that you are not showing.

Comment: I didn't add a trigger, never thought it was necessary.

Comment: Post the _full_ error message. This table, as already mentioned, has no unique index defined and therefore cannot ever cause the duplicate key error. It may be reported on a different table, or the definition for this table differs from what you posted. Show the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Client_Iofo.Session_log`

Comment: 'Session_log', 'CREATE TABLE `session_log` (\n  `Client_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `session_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `Staff_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `Session_Duration` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`Staff_ID`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Comment: @HalimoAbdule so it actually turns out you do have a primary key column, which is throwing you this duplication error :)

Comment: So you do have a primary key (which is a unique index) on `Staff_ID` but you are inserting duplicates for several Staff_ID values. If those are not intended to be unique, and one Staff_ID should have many rows in `Session_log`, drop the primary key constraint or if you haven't inserted anything yet, drop the whole table and recreate it with the `CREATE TABLE` statement you originally posted, having no index/primary key.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked